# Understanding dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

In my quest to try and understand dynamic SQL, I tried to start of simple by dynamically inserting the count of the number of rows from each tables of `sys.tables`.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT 
    Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID() ) AS SomeNumb
INTO
    #Dyn
FROM 
    sys.tables

CREATE TABLE ##Results (Cnt INT)    

DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Counter INT

SET @Counter = 1
SET @Table = (SELECT Name FROM #Dyn WHERE SomeNumb = @Counter)

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(1000)

WHILE @Counter <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Dyn)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ##ResultsTable
    SELECT @Sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM #Dyn WHERE 
    Name = ' + @Table + 'AND SomeNumb = ' + @Counter
    EXECUTE (@Sql)

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
    SET @Sql = ''
END

SELECT * FROM ##ResultsTable
```

The only good thing is that is does not error out. Although that might give me some direction. I know there are scope issues with my `ResultsTable`, but I thought using the `##` instead of # would fix that.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to use a CURSOR for this and you're not setting `@Table` variable to anything

Comment: in addition to @Mazhar you are doing SELECT .. INTO table that would actually supposed to fail after the first iteration as the table would exist already. It is not failing right now because table variable is not set as it is mentioned already. Anyway it is good way to print statements for debugging. If you would do PRINT(@@sql) instead of exec then you would see what was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the input, made some adjustments, as shown above, but now I get the following error message. An INSERT statement cannot contain a SELECT statement that assigns values to a variable.

Comment: As an aside, a much faster way of doing this for all tables at once is `SELECT object_name(t.object_id), sum(rows) FROM sys.partitions p JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = p.object_id WHERE p.index_id IN (0, 1) GROUP BY t.object_id`. The row count this obtains is only approximate (there is a `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE` command to update the estimates if they get out of sync), but for monitoring purposes a fast if possibly inaccurate row count can still be better than an accurate but excruciatingly slow row count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a reviewed script.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Dyn') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Dyn

SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID() ) AS SomeNumb
INTO #Dyn
FROM sys.tables

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ResultsTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ResultsTable

CREATE TABLE #ResultsTable (TotalRowCount INT)

DECLARE @Counter INT = 1
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE @Counter <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Dyn)
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(100) = (SELECT Name FROM #Dyn WHERE SomeNumb = @Counter)

    SELECT @Sql = '
        INSERT INTO #ResultsTable (TotalRowCount)
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt 
        FROM #Dyn 
        WHERE Name = ''' + @Table + ''' AND SomeNumb = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @Counter)

    EXECUTE (@Sql)

    SET @Counter += 1

END


SELECT * FROM #ResultsTable
```

Some things to mention:

- You can create a temporary table outside the EXEC and insert it inside dynamic SQL.
- Your `COUNT()` of the `#Dyn` table will always return 1 because there is only 1 record with a particular table name.
- You need to add additional quotes when printing varchar values (like @Table) on dynamic SQL:
- You need to convert all non literal values to `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` when building dynamic SQL (like `@Counter`).

---

**Edit**: If you want actual count for each table then you don't need to query `#Dyn`!

```
SELECT @Sql = '
    INSERT INTO #ResultsTable (TotalRowCount)
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt 
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Table) +

EXECUTE (@Sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and even more for the additional info!

Comment: If I want to count all the rows for each table, how do I get there? I tried to change the FROM #Dyn to FROM ( SELECT Name FROM #Dyn ) but that does not do the job.

Comment: @SQL_M in that case the FROM needs to be the dynamic table name, not Dyn. I've added an example at the end. Use PRINT(@Sql) instead of EXEC(@Sql) to see the built dynamic SQL and validate it before executing, it will be easier to spot mistakes.

Comment: About to throw my computer out the window. I need the #Dyn table to selects the tables row by row. What's wrong with this?   SELECT Sql = '
        INSERT INTO #ResultsTable (TotalRowCount)
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt 
        FROM ' + Table + '
        WHERE Name = ( SELECT Name FROM #Dyn WHERE SomeNumb = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), Counter))

Comment: I get incorrect syntax neer ')'. After this one, I wont waste your time anymore.

Comment: @SQL_M try using QUOTENAME() on the table name so it gets correctly escaped. Make sure to use PRINT to see errors.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a `CURSOR` or `WHILE` loop, One method is to use `sys.tables` and `sys.schemas` and `FOR XML PATH`:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = (SELECT N'SELECT ''' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) +''' AS ObjectName, COUNT(*) AS [RowCount]' + NCHAR(10) +
                   N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + N';' + NCHAR(10)
            FROM sys.tables t
                 JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.SCHEMA_ID = s.SCHEMA_ID
            FOR XML PATH(N''))

PRINT @SQL;
CREATE TABLE #Cnt (ObjectName sysname, [RowCount] int);
INSERT INTO #Cnt (ObjectName, [RowCount])
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

SELECT *
FROM #cnt;

DROP TABLE #cnt;
```

Alternatively, you can use the undocumented procedure `sp_msforeachtable`:

```
CREATE TABLE #Cnt (ObjectName sysname, [RowCount] int);
INSERT INTO #Cnt (ObjectName, [RowCount])
EXEC sp_msforeachtable N'SELECT ''?'' AS ObjectName, COUNT(*) AS [RowCount]
FROM ?;';

SELECT *
FROM #cnt;

DROP TABLE #cnt;
```

The latter method, however, does actually use a `CURSOR` if I recall correctly.

Comment: You don't have to recall correctly: `sp_helptext 'sp_msforeachtable'` will offer you a peek behind the covers. (Yes, it does use a cursor, in combination with dynamic SQL even, and an even more complicated inner procedure for the actual work.)

Comment: Thanks Larnu, I like the FOR XML path option, + one!